# Construct a function to "increment" a value while asymptotically approaching a limit

Tags: functions, puzzle

Suppose I have a value $a_1$ such that $-L < a_1 < L$. I need to compute $a_2$ from $a_1$ and $b$, while satisfying the following requirements:

- $-L < a_2 < L$
- if $b = 0$ then $a_2 = a_1$
- if $b < 0$ then $a_2 < a_1$
- if $b > 0$ then $a_2 > a_1$
- a *chaining* requirement, explained below.

The operation can be written as $a_2 = f(a_1, b)$ (with an implicit $L$ argument which I'll leave out for clarity). In this notation, the *chaining* requirement can be expressed as: $f(a, b+c) = f(f(a, b), c)$. In intuitive terms, adjusting $a$ by $b$ and *then* by $c$ produces the same result as adjusting $a$ by $b + c$.

Can you recommend a function $f$ that satisfies these requirements? If you constructed the function rather than just happened to know one that fits these, could you outline the steps?

(**edited** to fix the impossible $-L \le a \le $L requirement)

Comment: Addition of speeds in special relativity is sort of similar: $\frac{a+b}{1 + ab / L^2}$, but it only works for $b < L$ and doesn't satisfy the chaining requirement.

Comment: Note that you have to use the open interval ($-L < a < L$), not the closed one, since $f(L,b)$ can never be greater than $L$, and $f(-L,b)$ can never be less than $-L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easy, if it weren't impossible :-)
It's impossible because if (say) $a_1 = L$ and $b > 0$, then a suitable $a_2$ would have to be both $\le L$ and $\gt a_1$.
But suppose we restate the problem, so that $-L \lt a_1 \lt L$ and we require $-L \lt a_2 \lt L$. Now it's easy. All we need is a strictly increasing, invertible function

$g: (-L,L) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

For instance: $g(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi x}{2L})$, with inverse $g^{-1}(y)=\frac{2L}{\pi}tan^{-1}(y)$

Now define

$f(a,b) = g^{-1}(g(a)+b)$

and we're done.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, so I just wanted to add that if you express the solution as $f_b = g^{-1} \circ \operatorname{add}_b \circ g$, where $\operatorname{add}_b(a) := a + b$, then it is obvious that $$\begin{align} f_b \circ f_c &= g^{-1} \circ \operatorname{add}_b \circ g \circ g^{-1} \circ \operatorname{add}_c \circ g \\ &= g^{-1} \circ \operatorname{add}_b \circ \operatorname{add}_c \circ g \\ &= g^{-1} \circ \operatorname{add}_{b+c} \circ g \\ &= f_{b+c} \end{align}$$

Comment: @Rahul it appears that this "function algebra" is something I must have completely forgotten. Looks damn useful for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the restriction of domain and range to $(-L,L)$, ordinary addition would work: $f(a,b) = a+b$.  So if you take $g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-L,L)$ to be any increasing bijection, then $f(a,b) = g\left(g^{-1}(a) + b\right)$ will satisfy the requirements.  A nice specific example is $g(x) = L\tanh(x)$, whose inverse is $$g^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{L+x}{L-x}\right).$$
The desired function becomes
$$
f(a,b) = L \tanh\left(b + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{L+a}{L-a}\right)\right).
$$

Comment: The puzzle started off as ordinary addition, trying to add the -L/L restriction to it. That's why it resembles addition, like you say.